# Passing html value through hyperlink

Tags: html

I have a page with textbox and a hyperlink.

Requirement:

when the user clicks the hyperlink, the value from the textbox needs to be passed..Currently I have given a dummy value of "a".

```
<div>
    <input type="text"/>
    <a id="test" href="./csv/?value=a">Click</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use a form using a GET method?

Comment: That's not possible using plain HTML hyperlinks. You either need a `<form>` or use JavaScript.

Comment: Take a look at [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3784499/2966317)

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I cant use a get method..Right now the application, creates a spreadsheet response..If I change it, I have to handle that functionality using Jquery

Answer (score 2):

1. Give the input a name
2. Replace the link with a submit button
3. Put them in a form
4. Add CSS to make the button look like a link if you really, really, really want to.

such:

```
<form action="./csv/">
    <input type="text" name="value">
    <button>Click</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I can't have all the controls grouped into the same form...I need to take values from 4 controls thats in different part of the pages..

Comment: That isn't a technical problem unless you have other forms in the way. It does sound like a usability problem though.