# How to use csrf-token in POST-hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, django, post, hyperlink, csrf

I need to make a hyperlink in Django for a POST-request. For example, "Add to blacklist" in the menu. It's easy to do with a form with a submit button but I need a menu item not button. I found Javascript code for doing this but it gives me an error 403: CSRF token missing or incorrect. And I couldn't find understable for me information how to insert csrf-token into the Javascript function. I don't know Javascript, I write in Python.

Here's the function from [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/65237/Вызов-метода-post-через-ссылку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/65237/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-post-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function postToUrl(path, params, method) {
            method = method || "post"; 

            var form = document.createElement("form");
            form.setAttribute("method", method);
            form.setAttribute("action", path);
            for(var key in params) {
                var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
                hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

                form.appendChild(hiddenField);
            }

            document.body.appendChild(form);
            form.submit();
        }
    </script>
```

Here's how I call it:

```
<a href="#" onclick="postToUrl('/account/add_to_blacklist/watched_user_id{{ message.recipient.user.id }}/next={{ request.get_full_path }}', {}, 'POST');">To blacklist</a>
```

This is my view:

```
class AddToBlacklistView(View):

    def post(self, request, watched_user_id, next_url=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if not next_url:
            next_url = '../profile.html/user_id{0}'.format(watched_user_id)
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            try:
                user = User.objects.select_related("profile").get(username=request.user)
                watched_user = User.objects.select_related("profile").get(id=watched_user_id)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                raise Http404
            if watched_user.id == user.id:
                return redirect(next_url)
            if watched_user not in user.profile.blacklist.all():
                user.profile.blacklist.add(watched_user)
                user.save()
            if watched_user.profile in user.profile.friends.all():
                user.profile.friends.remove(watched_user.profile)
                if user.profile in watched_user.profile.friends.all():
                    friendship = Friendship.objects.get(user=watched_user.profile, friend=user.profile)
                    if friendship.status != 3:
                        friendship.status = 2
                        friendship.save()
            if watched_user in user.profile.bookmarks.all():
                user.profile.bookmarks.remove(watched_user)
            return redirect(next_url)
        else:
            return redirect(next_url)
```

I tried this and it didn't help:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token }}">
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
</script>
```

I also tried to pass as params this and it didn't help:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
```

Upd:
I also tried to add the decorator for a view and it continued to throw the same error:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    def post ...
```

I also tried @ method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie) on the view that renders the page with HTML that calls the Javascript function and I still get 403 error.

I also tried this code from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/ and it continued to throw the same 403 error.

```
        function getCookie(name) {
            let cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }

        const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

            function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
                // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
                return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
            }
            $.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here:
[submitting a hyperlink by GET or POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782689/submitting-a-hyperlink-by-get-or-post)

I had to modify it because on my page there is a list of people with a menu for each one of them in such a way:

```
<form id="myform1_{{ message.recipient.user.id }}" method="post" action="/account/add_to_blacklist/watched_user_id{{ message.recipient.user.id }}/next={{ request.get_full_path }}" >
{% csrf_token %}

</form>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myform1_{{ message.recipient.user.id }}').submit();">Add to blacklist</a>
```